# There should be an edit in installation manual for zsh and Mac users

Tags: stanford-nlp

Zsh doesn't recognise 'realpath', so 'readlink' should be used instead.

So that, instead:

```
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:javanlp-core.jar:stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar";
for file in `find lib -name "*.jar"`; do export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:`realpath $file`"; done
```

there should be:

```
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:javanlp-core.jar:stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar";
for file in `find lib -name "*.jar"`; do export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:`readlink $file`"; done
```

It would be nice if Stanford-NLP site maintainers mentioned it in the installation manual. Thanks!

Comment: Hi koscielna.  Stack Overflow is not Standford-NLP tech support, nor a place for feature requests.  You need to contact them directly.

Comment: Better to make issue on there github repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a Zsh issue; `realpath` is a program, not a builtin. On my mac, it lives at:

```
/usr/local/bin/realpath
```

I believe you can install it with:

```
brew install coreutils
```